# Numeric Hessian using gradient function R

Tags: r, optimization, numeric, numerical-methods

I need to calculate **Hessian** of my function **numerically** using **my gradient function** (programmed by **formula**, not numeric). Packages like `numDeriv` or `rootSolve` calculate hessian using **numerical** gradient that do not satisfy my needs. The thing I need performed **internally** (no separate method I can call) in `optim` package, however the only method that handles my optimization task well implemented in `nlopt` package and passing its optimal value to `optim` in order to get hessian is too expensive for my program.

So I need some function that calculates Hessian using not numeric gradient (see for example these formulas https://neos-guide.org/content/difference-approximations). I can't make such a function as I don't understand how to choose a parameter `h` (increment), that my function is very sensitive to. Could I find such a function in R or retrieve it somehow from `optim` package? Or may someone at least explain how to choose error minimizing value for `h` so then I will post this function by myself?

Comment: Hessian here is name of network protocol. Tag is selected wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should use `numDeriv::jacobian()`, which takes a vector-valued function and computes a matrix (the derivative of each element with respect to each input), and apply it to your analytical gradient function. `jacobian()` does use numerical approximation (Richardson extrapolation, to be precise), but I don't see any other way that you could get from a black-box gradient function to a Hessian?

You do need to specify (or use the default value) of a numerical 'delta' function (1e-4 by default). On the other hand, the internal code that `optim()` uses to compute the Hessian also uses finite differences: see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/R/optim.R#L81) and [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/src/optim.c#L430) ...

Below I define a function, its gradient function, and its Hessian; this code shows that `jacobian(grad(x))` is the same as the Hessian (for a particular test case).

```
library(numDeriv)
x1 <- c(1,1,1)
```

Test that I didn't screw up the gradient and Hessian functions:

```
all.equal(grad(f,x1),g(x1)) ## TRUE
all.equal(h(x1),hessian(f,x1)) ## TRUE
```

Numerical equivalence of my Hessian and the Jacobian of the gradient:

```
all.equal(h(x1),jacobian(g,x1)) ## TRUE
```

Test functions:

```
f <- function(x) {
  sin(x[1])*exp(x[2])*x[3]^2
}

g <- function(x) {
  c(cos(x[1])*exp(x[2])*x[3]^2,
    sin(x[1])*exp(x[2])*x[3]^2,
    sin(x[1])*exp(x[2])*2*x[3])
}  

h <- function(x) {
    m <- matrix(NA,3,3)
    m[lower.tri(m,diag=TRUE)] <-
        c(-sin(x[1])*exp(x[2])*x[3]^2,
          cos(x[1])*exp(x[2])*x[3]^2,
          cos(x[1])*exp(x[2])*2*x[3],
    # col 2
           sin(x[1])*exp(x[2])*x[3]^2,
           sin(x[1])*exp(x[3])*2*x[3],
    # col 3
           sin(x[1])*exp(x[2])*2)
    m <- Matrix::forceSymmetric(m,"L")
    m <- unname(as.matrix(m))
    return(m)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I need!